# Converting JSON/JS Object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON response from my API that is structured like so:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1", "name": "test"
    },
    {
      "id": "2", "name": "test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I reference data I get the array with each record.  I need the curly braces to be brackets due to a plugin I am using requiring it to be an array.

Desired output:

```
[
  ["1", "test"],
  ["2", "test"]
]
```

How can I convert the above JSON to this?

Edit:

This turned out to be a problem with a plugin I was using, and I knew how to do this fine all along.  Thought I was going crazy but my code was fine, some plugin was screwing things up.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you know how to iterate over an array or an object? You must have tried *something* before asking.

Comment: Yes I know how to iterate over an array/object.

Comment: Well, `JSON.stringify()` encodes an array or object as JSON. It doesn't change the structure of the array or object.

Comment: @NoahMatisoff: What were you expecting `JSON.stringify` to do? You have an array already, so just iterate through it and push the `id` and `name` into a new array of arrays.

Comment: You can iterate over **result.data** and then convert each row into an array that contains your row data.

Comment: The plugin requires it to be in the format that I posted.

Comment: *"Yes I know how to iterate over an array/object"* Then where are you stuck? You iterate over all elements of `obj.data`, create a new array for each, iterate over each property of the element and push it to the new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var arr = json.data.map(function(x){ 
   return [x.id, x.name]; 
});
```

Comment: @NoahMatisoff: Given the input from your question, it produces exactly the output you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/g9frwert/ . Assuming you parsed the JSON of course.

Comment: I added this code right after Angular's $http returns the data, console.log() it, but for some reason it's not working properly.

Comment: This solved my problem this issue must be with the plugin so I accepted this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:  http://jsfiddle.net/3gcg6Lbz/1/

```
var arr = new Array();
var obj = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1", "name": "test"
    },
    {
      "id": "2", "name": "test2"
    }
  ]
}

for(var i in obj.data) {
  var thisArr = new Array();
  thisArr.push(obj.data[i].id);
  thisArr.push(obj.data[i].name);
  arr.push(thisArr);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You should avoid using `for...in` loops to iterate over arrays.

Comment: I run and get this in the console...   [["1", "test"], ["2", "test2"]]

Comment: @FelixKling how do you typically iterate over arrays?

Comment: With a `for` loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Why do you choose for loop over for in?  It is for performance reasons?  I have heard for in is faster.  Just curious